# Select id from JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, app-inventor

I'm currently designing an app to display some attributes of products I have in a pricelist which is stored in a Google Sheets spreadsheet and I want it to get that data and show it

I have a google script which extracts all the data from the spreadsheet and returns a JSON. It's published as a web app and stored in a non visible component "Web1"

[image: Google Script result]

What I don't know how to do is to work with that JSON and select a particular row based on an ID that I get from a barcode scanner

[image: App interface]

I want it to work like this:

- Get a result from the barcode reader
- Display the result from the barcode scan in a textbox "Código de barras"
- Use that result to filter from a JSON which is extracted from the spreadsheet
- Display the JSON attribute "name" in the textbox "Producto"

I currently have this:

[image: App blocks]

Comment: Consider to store the data within a 2-D array rather than a Json. You can find the position (row)  of the scanned ID within the array with `indexOf()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp and retrieve the product name corresponding to this position.

Comment: If you're using dates then remember to store all of the your dates as strings rather than dates because you can't  use google.script.run to pass date objects between client and server. [parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web component works asynchronously, which means, first send the Get request and **after having received the response in the GotText event**, then do the further processing.

[image]